# Discrete measure and piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Hi guys, can anyone please help me with why we can introduce a sectionally constant function that has support $\lambda_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$. I do not understand why we can do the part I marked with blue pen. I think it's related to discrete measure but it's not too clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with discrete/counting measure (although it could be seen in that way). It is simply a Lebesgue-Stieljes integral (or a Riemann-Stieltjes integral). Also, the function has support on the whole the line minus at most some open interval (that can be infinite).

**A rough description is the following:**

The only difference (in the case of aRiemann-Stieltjes integral) is that lower and upper Riemann sums with respect to a partition are computed by taking limits of the expression
$$
\sum_{i=1}^kf(u_i)[\sigma_n(u_i)-\sigma_n(u_{i-1})],
$$
with $f(u)=u^k$ in your example, instead of
$$
\sum_{i=1}^kf(u_i)(u_i-u_{i-1}).
$$
But since $\sigma_n$ only changes at the points $\lambda_i$ it suffices to consider partitions with intervals whose endpoints are close to the $\lambda_i$'s. Taking the limit when these intervals approach the points $\lambda_i$, the number $\sigma_n(u_i)-\sigma_n(u_{i-1})$ approaches $\mu_i$ thus giving your formula (2.5).